# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to model

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

After looking at Stackoverflow questions I could not find any solution that fix this problem.

I am trying to use GSON and have implemented a generic method like this:

```
public <T> List<T> deserializeList(String json) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = (new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}).getType();
    return  gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Call to this method is done through this :

```
parser.<Quote>deserializeList(result)
```

However the result that I am getting is this:

[image]

And when I am trying to access an object, I get this error:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to model.Quote
```

The JSON string is:

```
[
    {
      "id": 269861,
      "quote": "People living deeply have no fear of death.",
      "author": "Anais Nin",
      "genre": "life",
      "tag": null,
      "createdAt": "2016-04-16T13:13:36.928Z",
      "updatedAt": "2016-04-16T13:13:36.928Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: I don't think that's how you are supposed to call that method with a type parameter

Comment: @cricket_007 with or without does not matter - parser.deserializeList(result)

Comment: That's what I thought. Now, what is `T` in the class definition? Secondary question, could you be using Retrofit?

Comment: @cricket_007 no T in class definition as it is a generic method. No, I am not  using Http as yet; a static JSON is in raw resource that I need to parse. it has been working till I have made this as a generic method. So I just wanted to know how it has affected. If I hard code the TypeToken with the type of specific class then it works well .But then I am repeating the same for all different json that I have.

Comment: Why not give the method a `Type` parameter instead of trying to use generics?

Comment: @cricket_007 Probably it can work but I have a multiple implementation of same interface; those having a Type as a parameter will make a unique Interface, which then I cannot have multiple implementation because not every JSON parser need Type. Let me try with your  suggestion ... but I still want to know why it is happening :)

Comment: @cricket_007 as expected it has worked. But why it is not working as a template method ? ! I will up your comments as the solution of why the original question is not working is still open :)

Answer (score 2):

I would think you could write the method like so to explicitly provide the `Type`

```
public <T> List<T> deserializeList(String json, Type type) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return  gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Though, passing around `(new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {}).getType();` looks a little messy.

I'm not too familiar with type erasure, but I bet that's related to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The above parsing method is wrong and the following code is modified:

```
public static <T> List<T> getObjectList(String jsonString,Class<T> cls){
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonArray arry = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : arry) {
            list.add(gson.fromJson(jsonElement, cls));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, you can define a reified extension function like:

```
internal inline fun <reified T> Gson.fromJson(json: String) =
    fromJson<T>(json, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
```

And then use it like:

```
val resultJson = "{...}"
val quotesList: List<Quote> = gson.fromJson(resultJson)
```

**Explanation:** at runtime, all generic types are erased (the compiler can create completely correct code without keeping the generic types at runtime). But if you declare a type as `reified`, you gain the ability to use that type within the function at runtime.